# Arquillian Does Not Execute More Than 4 Tests

Tags: jboss-arquillian

This one is a bit of a headscratcher: I have an Arquillian test class with 8 tests. If I execute 4 of them at once, all of them work, but if I add even one other test, the last one fails. If I execute all 8 of them, the last 4 fail. If I change the the order, still the last 4 fail. There is no rhyme nor reason to which ones get executed and which one fails besides that.

(The same holds true if I put half of the tests in another class. Then both classes execute fine on their own, but if they are started as part of the same run configuration, the second one will fail all its tests.)

The error occurs inside the `@Before` method, so here it is:

```java
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Inject
private UserTransaction transaction;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  Assert.assertNotNull("EntityManager cannot be null!", this.em);

  this.transaction.begin();
  this.em.createNativeQuery(MY_SCRIPT_1).executeUpdate();
  this.em.createNativeQuery(MY_SCRIPT_2).executeUpdate();
  this.transaction.commit();
}
```

Where `MY_SCRIPT_X` is a bunch of code, but the relevant portion might be:

```sql
-- MY_SCRIPT_1

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS scheme1 CASCADE;
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS scheme2 CASCADE;
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;

-- MY_SCRIPT_2

CREATE TABLE scheme1.dbconfig (
  propkey character varying NOT NULL, 
  propvalue character varying NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT dbconfig_pkey PRIMARY KEY (propkey)
);
COMMENT ON TABLE scheme1.dbconfig IS 'global database configuration properties';

INSERT INTO scheme1.dbconfig VALUES
  ('initialized', true),
  ('version', 2);
```

The error does not occur if I use only one big script [`em.createNativeQuery(MY_SCRIPT_1 + MY_SCRIPT_2)`], even though the table `scheme1.dbconfig` is only referenced in one of the files.

All I get as an error message is:

> 09:20:18,243 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-24) ERROR: relation "scheme1.dbconfig" does not exist
>     Position: 169

I have no idea where position 169 is (ignoring all comments, the 169th position should be between the R and the O of `propkey`, which seems odd). But I checked the database after executing the entire class and getting the above error, and the table `scheme1.dbconfig` does indeed exist.

I know, it's an oddly specific problem, but does anybody what the problem might be (or even how to debug it further)?

---

Some more infos:

- **database**: PostgreSQL
- **Hibernate**: 4.3.5
- **container**: Wildfly 8.1.0.Final

And all it needs for my to reproduce the bug is (the *beans.xml* is an default empty file, and the *persistence.xml* has only the `jta-data-source`):

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class BugTest {

private static final String CLEANUP_SCRIPT = "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS scheme1 CASCADE; "
        + "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS public CASCADE; " 
        + "CREATE SCHEMA public AUTHORIZATION testdba;";
private static final String CREATE_SCRIPT = "CREATE SCHEMA scheme1; "
        + "CREATE TABLE scheme1.dbconfig ( propkey character varying NOT NULL, propvalue character varying NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT dbconfig_pkey PRIMARY KEY (propkey) ); "
        + "INSERT INTO scheme1.dbconfig VALUES ('initialized', true), ('version', 2);";

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addAsManifestResource("META-INF/beans.xml", "beans.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "persistence.xml");
}

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Inject
private UserTransaction transaction;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.transaction.begin();
    this.em.createNativeQuery(CLEANUP_SCRIPT).executeUpdate();
    this.em.createNativeQuery(CREATE_SCRIPT).executeUpdate();
    this.transaction.commit();
}

// since an exception gets thrown in the setUp() method, these are not called
// they are only needed because the exception gets thrown for more than
// four tests methods
@Test public void test1() { }
@Test public void test2() { }
@Test public void test3() { }
@Test public void test4() { }
@Test public void test5() { }
@Test public void test6() { }
@Test public void test7() { }
@Test public void test8() { }
}
```

Comment: Just spitballing, but I would guess this has something to do with the test runner splitting the tests into parallel jobs if there's more than a thresholded number of them.

Comment: @Sneftel I disabled parallel tests in Maven and AFAIK Eclipse doesn't do parallel at all, so it can't be that.

Comment: This is super abstract.  The more information you can provide, the better.  What DB provider? What version of hibernate? What container are you running?f  Can you provide the full test? The full error (you're only including 1 line)?

Comment: @JohnAment I added the information to the question. Sadly, there is no stacktrace or anything, just the one line (the JUnit / Client side only wraps that line into an `ArquillianProxyException`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran over that problem again and again and again in the previous two years. The only thing that reliable works are the following:

- using one script instead of two; in this case, I'll concatenate the two files before executing
- not initializing every time; I'll test if one of the schemata is present and hope and pray that the previous tests left the database in an usable    condition (good luck debugging using this one)

Answer (score -1):

No, Arquillian will run as many tests as you need in a single file, or at least until JUnit (or TestNG) stop running. Here are some examples from Apache DeltaSpike with more than four tests running:

https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/impl/src/test/java/org/apache/deltaspike/test/core/impl/exception/control/handler/CallingHandlersTest.java

https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/modules/data/impl/src/test/java/org/apache/deltaspike/data/impl/handler/EntityRepositoryHandlerTest.java

https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/impl/src/test/java/org/apache/deltaspike/test/core/api/message/MessageContextTest.java

You must have something in your setup that is causing the problem.

Comment: Not even one of the tests classes has a `@Before` method setting up the database...

Comment: Your question didn't ask about that, it asked if more than four tests could be run. Try taking a look at the Arquillian Persistence Extension as it will take care of a bunch of this infrastructure code for you.

Comment: Maybe you should read the question again (hint: it's the sentence ending in a question mark).

Comment: Seems like you're hitting a race condition where an insert is happening after another test has dropped the scheme. Arquillian Persistence should help here.